# Alternative to Samba with XAMP stack

Tags: apache-2.2, samba, git, lamp, server-message-block

I am currently setting up a server on my network for web development work and was wondering if there is any better way of doing what I intend to do.

My work machine is a Windows 7 desktop and I am virtualizing an Ubuntu server to act as my LAMP stack. Now, to get projects to and from my windows machine for editing I am going to configure a samba share on the server of the entire www/ directory, and map it to a drive in windows.

I will also be using git to push changes up to my web server as my online staging area, enabling me to preview my work to my bosses etc.

I quite like the workflow of git & pushing to a remote server in particular, I'm also not a major fan of mapped drives, if I shut down the Linux machine and have files open, programs with these files open start to freeze out which is also quite irritating.

I was thinking potentially I could configure git on my local Linux server and push to it separate from my webserver but one of the things I do like about my mapped drives setup is being able to make changes and see them happen without having to do git add / git commit / git push everytime.

I work alone so I'm not 100% on what the best practices are, and I may just have to take a decision of one of the two options I seem to have, but I wanted to post here to see if there is a better way of doing things, as I'm always keen to learn if there is.

Security is not a key issue here, but if there are security issues I would like to hear them.

Thanks

Comment: What virtualization software are you using?

Comment: I'm using VMWare Player

Answer (score 1):

If you're working alone, you can make use of some of the options that fuse offers, like [SSHFS](https://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/), with the windows components, you can have mapped drives more securely, you can even set up keys and do passwordless entry. I'm not a huge fan of samba, not because it's a bad program, it just has to replicate a bad protocol as faithfully as possible unfortunately.

Comment: +1, I've never heard of this before. I was going to suggest sftp of course as that is common practice.